# While using pip install: Required library boost not found

Tags: python, boost

I am trying to install via `pip install` a python module. But when I do it, it gives me this:

```
RuntimeError: Required library Boost not found.
```

Now, I have already downloaded boost. I put it in program files/boost (hopefully that is how it's done because the boost web page doesn't give much detail on the installation except to download and extract).   So I am not sure what the problem is. I have tried to do cd program files/boost, but that doesn't work either. The instruction from the [documentation](http://dan.iel.fm/transit/current/quickstart/) is pretty vague too.

First time I am doing this, so I can't tell if what I am doing is dreadfully wrong or not.

Answer (score 1):

> Now, I have already downloaded boost. I put it in program files/boost (hopefully that is how it's done because the boost web page doesn't give much detail on the installation except to download and extract)

No, that's not how it's done, and that's your problem.

Also, I don't know where you got the idea that the Boost web page doesn't give much detail on installation. There's a huge [Getting Started](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/more/getting_started/) document.

Of course that documentation tells you how to build C++ programs that you're writing against Boost; it doesn't tell you how to convince Python to find it for modules that depend on Boost.Python. That's in the [Boost.Python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/python/doc/index.html) docs.

Also note that [Christoph Gohlke's unofficial Windows Python Binaries](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#boost.python) includes a `boost.python` package, which installs all the Python-side runtime stuff for you, which makes it a bit easier.

This isn't simple. (It's a lot simpler on Unix systems (including Macs), where, as long as you install a C or C++ library into some standard path, every other program can find it.) But I doubt anyone is going to be able to provide a better tutorial in a StackOverflow answer than the one in the official docs, so you're just going to have to read them.

Comment: I see, so there are many additional steps that needed to be done. I had the wrong idea because I had the impression the other instructions were more about usage than installation. For example, one section is "build a simple program using boost" which was not something I wanted to do. Also thank you for the additional resources.

Would a good first step be to download the windows python binary or should I first do the steps in the boost.python docs?

Comment: @ibyea: Well, you _do_ want to build a simple program using boost—you want to build that module. Anyway, I haven't used the Windows binary. In fact, I've never built any `pip`-installed packages that use boost.python on Windows. I don't think too many people do that. But yeah, try it, see what it installs. The key point is that you need to (1) get Python/setuptools aware of your Boost install path, and (2) get a Boost Python DLL build against your Python version, and the binary installer will at least solve (2), and maybe (1).

Comment: Okay, I installed the python binary. How do I do (1)? Tried all sorts of cd commands, but that didn't work.

Comment: Also tried adding additional directory in the path variable.